# Laravel Factory Deeply Nested Relationships Failure

Tags: laravel, eloquent, factory

I am running into an issue where factories with deeply nested relationships are not executing correctly from DB foreign key errors.

I have a series of factories used to propagate data into the DB via the app models. When I run all base level (factories with not relations) factories, I have no issues. When I run all single level factories (factories with a single relation), I have no issues. However, when I run any second level factories (factories with a relation to another factory that has a relation to another) I get the DB error.

In simple terms that means I can run the `ProductKeyFactory` and `ActivationCodeFactory` themselves with no issue. This only happens when I attempt to run the `FeatureActivationFactory`

My factories

```
class FeatureActivationFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = FeatureActivation::class;

    /** @var string $connection DB Connection */
    protected $connection = License::DB;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'code_id' => ActivationCode::factory(),
            'productSoftware_id' => ProductSoftware::factory(),
            'date' => now()
        ];
    }
}

class ActivationCodeFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = ActivationCode::class;

    /** @var string $connection DB Connection */
    protected $connection = License::DB;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'key_id' => ProductKey::factory(),
            'code' => $this->faker->lexify('??????????'),
            'isActive' => 0
        ];
    }
}

class ProductKeyFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = ProductKey::class;

    /** @var string $connection DB Connection */
    protected $connection = License::DB;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->unique->word,
            'startDate' => now(),
            'endDate' => $this->faker->dateTimeThisYear()
        ];
    }
}
```

My Factory error `FeatureActivation::factory()->create();`:

***Removed incorrect error message.***

### EDIT

Thank you to everyone for pointing out my stupid mistake. Yes that was an error I received due to a duplicate name but that wasn't the error I end up getting. Thank you for pointing out the `unique` feature - I added that to avoid that error. See the correct error message below:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`license`.`activationCodes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ActivationCodes_KeyID` FOREIGN KEY (`key_id`) REFERENCES `activationCodes` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT) (SQL: insert into `activationCodes` (`key_id`, `code`, `isActive`) values (18, zvszgdrrlj, 0))'
```

Comment: Are you refreshing your database before calling your factories, and only calling your factory once? The error is quite clear, you already have an entry with `name`="December" and you've defined that column with a unique index.

Comment: @miken32 I copied the wrong error message by mistake but you are correct in pointing this out - I added the unique method and changed the random string to another method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with unique indexes you need to tell Faker to avoid generating the same month name.

```
class ProductKeyFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = ProductKey::class;

    /** @var string $connection DB Connection */
    protected $connection = License::DB;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->unique()->monthName,
            'startDate' => now(),
            'endDate' => $this->faker->dateTimeThisYear()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - I was not aware of the unique function of the faker library. I copied the wrong error by mistake and so the unique key error was an issue but not the end issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an error on my part. Nested relationships do work, however, it is important to test any that are declared in your models to ensure they are working correctly - especially when using more complicated ones such as `hasOnThrough` and such, especially combined with columns that do not follow the laravel/eloquent naming convention exactly.